# iphone application - trace all method calls

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, debugging

I have developed an iphone application and submitted to the app store. Now, if anyone downloads the application and if the app gets crashed, i get a crash log from app store. But i could not understand how the crash occured.

So, i would like to trace all method calls in my application and the last fired event. If this information is captured and sent to me whenever an app crashes, i can solve the issue easily.

Is there a way to trace all method calls of an app ? 
I dont prefer adding NSLog for all the methods. ([Tracing the method calls in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730126/1538079))

When i run the code in XCODE, console logs gets generated. Is there a way i can create similar logs from my app ?

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in the same situation. Here's what I do for my apps.

For logging your own data, use [Cocoalumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack). It is much faster than NSLog and can be turned on/off dynamically. It also provides options to save the data into a file. NSLog will slow down your app and fills the console log. Also you don't want to log too much in general. You cannot safely do logging when the crash happens. So rather once you figured out where the problem area is, add some more logging there and try to reproduce it, e.g. by using automated testing frameworks like [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF).

More from here - [iOS crash log catch, debug info.. Catch and send via email to the Dev team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team)

Hope this helps...